# Как получить список не системных пользователей Debian

Tags: linux, debian

Как получить список не системных юзеров на сервере?

Comment: можете дать четкое определение "не системного пользоввтеля"?

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F: '($3>=1000)&&($1!="nobody"){print $1}' /etc/passwd
```